# Create Active Directory Group using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am creating an Web app for managing an Active Directory. I want to create a group in a certain container.

```
var groups = new List<Models.Group>();

PrincipalContext ctx = 
 new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, container, userName, password);

GroupPrincipal oGroupPrincipal = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
oGroupPrincipal.Description = mGroup.GroupName;
oGroupPrincipal.GroupScope = mGroup.GroupScope;
oGroupPrincipal.IsSecurityGroup = mGroup.IsSecurity;
oGroupPrincipal.Save();
```

but I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupScope?'

I am not sure how to handle this. How should I convert the GroupScope into an object GroupScope while it is a object string in my list?

I also got this error:

> SamAccountName or Name must be assigned to a newly-created Principal object in this store > prior to saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group scope is an enum with values of local, global and universal, it looks like you haven't cast the incoming value.

Try setting this to a static value:

```
oGroupPrincipal.GroupScope = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupScope.Local;
```

If this clears the error then try parsing your incoming string:

```
oGroupPrincipal.GroupScope = (System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupScope)Enum.Parse(typeof(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupScope),value);
```

Comment: I get this error when trying to do the above mentioned.Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupScope?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: ah enum.parse will return an object you'll need a cast I missed have edited

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
GroupPrincipal oGroupPrincipal = new GroupPrincipal(ctx, samAccountName);
```

And

```
oGroupPrincipal.Save(ctx);
```

Code samples for Active Directory -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#

[Active Directory With C#](http://www.ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm)